# Highlight table row background color in groups

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table being rendered dynamically from an ASP.NET gridview control which has 21 rows and I would like the background color to alternate in groups of 3.  I would like the rows 1-3 to have a background color of white, 4-6 background color of gray, 7-9 white, 10-12, gray, 13-15 white etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for jquery way you can achieve like below:

```js
counter = 1; // intialize counter
$('#table tbody tr').filter(function() {
  counter <= 3 ? $(this).addClass('white-tr') : $(this).addClass('grey-tr') 
  counter = counter == 6 ? 1 : counter+1; // once the counter reaches 6 set back to 1
});
```

```css
body{
  background: #000;
 }
.white-tr{
 background: white;
 }
 .grey-tr{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 21</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two classes in CSS and apply them manually or dynamically to each row in the table. Hope this helps. See the snippet for an example:

```css
.row-a {
  background-color: white;
}

.row-b {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-b'>
      <td>Row 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-a'>
      <td>Row 21</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```